# How can I increment a value (which is in the main class) from a different class

Tags: java, class, variables, int, increment

I want to add one to a value which is in the main class from another class But the error keeps pointing at "Balance".

The error occurs in my other class "RevenueThread", when I have said to get the class and then variable then increment by 1.

Here's the full code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

public static void main (String [] args){

    boolean running = true;
    boolean property1 = false;

    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Balance = 0;

    String option = "";



    Load:
    while(running){

        System.out.println("Choose an option");
        if(property1 == true){
            Runnable rev = new RevenueThread();
            Thread revThread = new Thread(rev);
            revThread.start();
        }
        System.out.println("Option 1: Buy Property");
        System.out.println("Option 2: Check balance");
        System.out.println();
        option = in.next();


        switch(option){

            case "1":
                System.out.println("Do you want to buy a property?: ");
                String ans = in.next();
                ans = ans.toUpperCase();
                if(ans.equals("Y")){
                    property1 ^= true;
                    continue Load;
                }
                else if(ans.equals("N")){
                    System.out.println("Property not bought come again soon!");
                    continue Load;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Not recognised!");
                    continue Load;
                }
                break;

            case "2":
                System.out.println("Your balance is: " + balance);
                continue Load;
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
}
public static class RevenueThread implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        while(true){


            Main.Balance++;

            try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println( ex.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Make it `class variable` which you want to access from another class.(in your case `Balance`)

Local variables are not visible outside method in which they are declared.

keep this statament

```
int Balance = 0;
```

before main method and make it static.After that you will be able to access it like this

```
Main.Balance++;
```